# cascade delete is not working as expected

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have 2 entities: the first one is User, and the second one is Log.

```
class User
{
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'user', targetEntity: Log::class, cascade: ["remove"], orphanRemoval: true)]
    private $logs;
}

class Log
{
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'logs')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $user = null;
}
```

When I remove an user, logs are not deleted ..

I tried different method:

A

```
$user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->find(1);
$this->em->remove($user);
$this->em->flush();
```

A is attempting to delete a User, but it's not working due to an integrity constraint violation.

B

```
$user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->find(1);
foreach ($user->getLogs() as $log) {
  $this->em->remove($log);
  $user->removeLog($log);
}
$this->em->remove($user);
$this->em->flush();
```

B has the same error.

I can't use an intermediate flush. I encounter this error in some projects. Did I miss something?

Edit:

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mybdd`.`logs`, CONSTRAINT `FK_536CA7E8CA939FD` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
```

Comment: It looks like it should have worked. Have you checked, that the mapping is correct via `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` and `bin/console doctrine:mapping:info`? and have you cleared the cache in between your tests and subsequent code changes? also the exact error message might help, although I'm not hopeful ;o/

Comment: No error with the commands :(

Comment: so, what imho would work, is flushing an extra time after the `foreach` completes in B, but that's not really cool, since doctrine *should* be able to order its operations on its own. but apparently this doesn't work. in theory, doctrine tries to order operations according to the dependencies the relations incur. this will be screwed up, if there is a dependency cycle or the dependencies are defined wrong. this might not show up in the mapping info as an error as two entities might depend on each other, even if this wouldn't work to remove them (because you could unset relation values)

Comment: I think you should use #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'cascade')] on User in Log